# How to exchange colors between 2 images?

Tags: numpy, opencv

I have an image of spectacles with black background that I need to overlay onto a face image. To do so, I am taking the part of face image with shape same as spectacles; and put the colors of face image on black parts of the spectacles image. Then this small part of image can be put back. But I am not being able to take the correct colors from face image for the spectacles image. I tried this :

```
specs[np.where((hmd == [0,0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = sub_face
```

specs image:

[image]

face image:

[image]

I need to put a resized specs image to face. I have resized specs image and also know the position where I will place the specs on face image. I just need to remove black background from specs and add relevant face colors so it looks like there are specs on face in a natural way.

Code I am using :

```
import cv2

specs = cv2.imread("rot_h0v0z0.png")
face = cv2.imread("~/Downloads/celebA/000001.png")
specs = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

sub_face = face[0:specs.shape[0], 0:specs.shape[1]]
specs[np.where((hmd == [0,0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = sub_face
```

Was able to solve it, turned out pretty simple :P

```
(b,g,r) = cv2.split(specs)
indices = np.where(b == [0])
for i,j in zip(indices[0], indices[1]):
    specs[i,j] = sub_face[i,j]
```

Comment: You should add the images and the expected result, so to clear more what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it, turned out pretty simple :P

```
(b,g,r) = cv2.split(specs)
indices = np.where(b == [0])
for i,j in zip(indices[0], indices[1]):
    specs[i,j] = sub_face[i,j]
```